# Getting join table data into Yii2 gridview

Tags: yii, yii2

I have 3 tables that i basically need to display in the single gridview.

- property
- sale (FK property_id)
- sale_staff (FK sale_id, staff_id)
- staff

Now a staff member can be a lister, a seller, or both, and each sale can have multiple lister or sellers.
So table `sale_staff` has column 'staff_type' with possible enum values `lister',`seller`.

So the gridview must have a display something like

```
property street | sale price | sale date | lister | seller
```

and the lister/seller fields should be able to display simple initials comma separated like `MJ, AB`.  This `initial` field comes from the staff table, which as above is linked to sale_staff via id.

I have not seen this type of scenario before so im simply unsure of how to incorporate the `sale_type` into the search so that only a staff listed as `lister` or `seller` is shown in that place.

Also, if i try something like this, just to see if anything is pulled back:

```
'attribute' => 'saleStaff.staff_id.initials'
```

or

```
'attribute' => 'saleStaff.staff'
```

I get `(not set)` in the gridview.

I have relations set up as:
Sale:

```
public function getProperty()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Property::className(), ['id' => 'property_id']);
}

public function getSaleStaff()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SaleStaff::className(), ['sale_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Sale_Staff:

```
public function getStaff()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Staff::className(), ['id' => 'staff_id']);
}

public function getSale()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Sale::className(), ['id' => 'sale_id']);
}
```

How do I match up the join table sale_staff with the sale table ? Is the structure ok or is DB incorrect ? I have done it this way to be flexible - any number of staff can be either a lister, seller, or both such as:

```
property street | sale price | sale date | lister | seller
Parkers Road    |  400,000   | 22/06/2016| MJ     | MJ, AB
```

Naturally, key question is how to represent multiple (unknown number of) values in a single gridview column like that.

Comment: Could you provide the full content of Sale_Staff model ? What is the structure of this table?

Comment: i have added the other hasOne code for Sale_Staff - but the rest is standard behavior rules i dont want to clog up the post :)